# "No code signature found" error when code signing is off xcode

Tags: xcode, build, ipod, signing

I am trying to put an xcode project on my ipod 2, I've had to downgrade the app which I've done successfully, I have disabled code signing on everything that needs it disabled, my ipod is jailbroken but i still get "No code signature" when it builds. Two of the errors open up if this means anything.

edit:
It now says Invalid Argument

Comment: Hi! I don't know about your problem, sorry, just to let you know that "coco" is the programming language.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too,

All you need to do is a clean build and it should sort it straight out, cmd shift K.

If that doesn't work straight away uninstall your app from the device and then clean build onto the device and the run and should work as before.